# Взаимодействие с потоками данных из социальных сетей

Tags: java, android

В телефонной книге представленны следующие возможности социальных сетей, как добавить такие же возможности в свое приложение?

[image]

Через поставщик контактов добираюсь до нужных строк.

```
Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);
            Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
            Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(entityUri,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA_ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.MIMETYPE,
                            ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA1,
                            ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA2,
                            ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA3},
                    null, null, null);
            try {
                while (c.moveToNext()) {
                    String sourceId = c.getString(0);

                if (!c.isNull(1)) {
                    String mimeType = c.getString(2);
                    String data = c.getString(3);
                    Log.d(TAG, "sourceId = "  + sourceId);
                    Log.d(TAG, "mimeType = "  + mimeType);
                    Log.d(TAG, "data = "  + data);
                    Log.d(TAG, "data = "  + c.getString(4));
                    Log.d(TAG, "data = "  + c.getString(5));

                }
            }
        } finally {
            c.close();
        }
```

Вот лог
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А как дальше запустить нужный `Intent`?
Пытаюсь таким образом

```
Uri singleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId);

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(singleUri, "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.vkontakte.android.profile");
                startActivity(intent);
```

Но ничего не выходит, что я делаю не так?

**Решение найдено, может кому полезно будет**

```
String contactId = "111"; // - id пользователя в таблице ContactsContract.Contacts

long rawContactId = 0; // - id пользователя в таблице ContactsContract.RawContacts
```

Запрашиваем данные для контакта от различных аккаунтов

```
Cursor curIcon = getActivity().getContentResolver().
                            query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{contactId }, null);

                    curIcon.moveToFirst();
                    do
                    {
                        rawContactId = curIcon.getLong(curIcon.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts._ID));
                        Log.d(TAG, "rawContactId = "  + rawContactId);
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACCOUNT_TYPE = "  + curIcon.getString(curIcon.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE)));

                    } while (curIcon.moveToNext());
                    curIcon.close();
```

Запрашиваем данные контакта из таблицы ContactsContract.Data

```
     Uri rawContactUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, rawContactId );
                        Uri entityUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(rawContactUri, ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
                        Cursor c = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(entityUri,
                                new String[]{ContactsContract.RawContacts.SOURCE_ID, 
                                             ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA_ID, // _id записи в таблице  ContactsContract.Data
                                             ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.MIMETYPE,  // тип данных
                                             ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA1,  //  тут будет идентефикатор пользователя
                                             ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA2,  // тут будет название соцсети
                                             ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA3},  // тут будет описание действия/функции
                                null, null, null);
                        try {
                            while (c.moveToNext()) {

                                if (!c.isNull(1)) {
                                    String mimeType = c.getString(2);
                                    long data_id = c.getLong(1);
                                    Log.d(TAG, "data_id = "  + data_id );
                                    Log.d(TAG, "mimeType = "  + mimeType);


                                }
                            }
                        } finally {
                            c.close();
                        }
```

Ну и запускаем нужную функцию

```
Uri singleUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, data_id );

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(singleUri, mimeType );
                startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо еще указывать пакет, который будет обрабатывать ваш `Intent`. Например отсылка сообщения через Viber будет выглядеть так:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setPackage("com.viber.voip");
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello World!");
```

Обратите внимание на `putExtra()` - он для каждого Intent'а свой - подозреваю, что для вконтакте он тоже свой - почитайте доки.

**Update**

Чтобы открыть диалог вконтакте для конкретного контакта, надо вызывать:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
    Uri.parse(String.format("vkontakte://profile/%d", contactId)));
```

где `contactId` - идентификатор контакта

Comment: Это я уже пробовал. Данный вариант не откроет диалог с нужным контактом, он откроет приложение, где в дальнейшем нужно выбрать получателя. А как получить доступ напрямую к диалогу с конкретным пользователем в конкретном приложении?

Comment: Тогда переформулируйте вопрос - что вы хотите то? `Intent` в вашем исполнении все равно просьба открыть другое приложение...

Comment: После обращения к поставщику контактов я получаю данные таблицы "RawContacts" для конкретного контакта, внесенные туда конкретным приложением, эти данные видны в логах. mimeType - как я понимаю тип данных, присваиваются интенту методом setType, у нужного приложения есть настроенный интент фильтр для его перехвата, а вот как передать идентефикатор пользователя (он содержится в столбце ContactsContract.RawContacts.Entity.DATA1)

Comment: То есть вы хотите открыть книгу контактов в другом приложении (вернее диалог с нужным контактом)? Если так то переформулируйте вопрос. Иначе вопрос вводит в заблуждение относительно ваших намерений

Comment: Вопрос куда надо, по моему первое предложение вопроса и первый скриншот исчерпывающе поясняют суть вопроса. Функции соцсетей появляются после синхронизации приложения соцсети, а для их реализации необходимо обратиться к поставщику контактов за необходимыми данными, как раз этот процес мне и был не понятен.

Comment: @АндрейРябов, жизнь надо принимать такой какая она есть, а именно, если респондент не понимает ваш вопрос - не пытаться говорить, что вопрос составлен верно, а просто переформулировать вопрос/объяснить. Да, мир несовершенен, респонденты - идиоты и не понимают простейших вопросов :)

Comment: Решение найдено, спасибо за участие ))!

Comment: Просьба опубликовать ваше решение, может потом еще кому то понадобится